# Is there any Powershell module similar to Python prettytable?

Tags: python, powershell

In python we have [prettytable](https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/) module for easily displaying tabular data in a visually appealing ASCII table format.

```
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| City name | Area | Population | Annual Rainfall |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| Adelaide  | 1295 |  1158259   |      600.5      |
| Brisbane  | 5905 |  1857594   |      1146.4     |
| Darwin    | 112  |   120900   |      1714.7     |
| Hobart    | 1357 |   205556   |      619.5      |
| Melbourne | 1566 |  3806092   |      646.9      |
| Perth     | 5386 |  1554769   |      869.4      |
| Sydney    | 2058 |  4336374   |      1214.8     |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
```

Do we have anything similar module in PowerShell?

Comment: Try also `Out-GridView` for a graphical alternative. It's got sorting and filtering too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical answer is of course `Format-Table`, as mentioned by others.

Where Ajay says "it gets scrambled" is due to a misapprehension of the output of `Format-Table` and `Format-List`. These commands output internal markup. That markup is rendered by the engine to stdout. It is *not* rendered if you pipe the output of a `Format` command to another command (say, `ConvertTo-Html`). In that case, the next command receives the markup instead of the raw data, which is almost never what you want.

The markup is *also* rendered by `Out-String`. So do this:

```
> $AsciiTable = Get-Process pwsh | Format-Table | Out-String
```

Output:

```
> $AsciiTable

 NPM(K)    PM(M)      WS(M)     CPU(s)      Id  SI ProcessName
 ------    -----      -----     ------      --  -- -----------
    115   143.79     207.55       9.55    1080   1 pwsh
     92   129.62     188.68      10.77    2340   1 pwsh
     89   125.49     183.95      11.31   11352   1 pwsh
```

To get a `[string[]]` instead of a multi-line `[string]`, use `Out-String -Stream`.

To trim the empty lines at the head and foot, use `.Trim()`:

PSv5+: `$AsciiTable = Get-Process pwsh | Format-Table | Out-String | ForEach-Object Trim`

Older PS: `$AsciiTable = Get-Process pwsh | Format-Table | Out-String | ForEach-Object {$_.Trim()}`

### Alternatives

#### ConvertTo-Markdown

*Ships with PSv7, present on 7.2.6, YMMV on older versions*

```
> Get-ChildItem | Select-Object Mode, LastWriteTime, Length, Name | ConvertTo-Markdown
Mode  | Name            | LastWriteTime
----- | --------------- | -------------------
d---- | dotfiles        | 05/10/2022 11:35:34
d---- | Notes           | 05/10/2022 11:29:09
d---- | oneget          | 06/10/2022 18:50:00
```

If I specifically wanted a close match to the `prettytable` output and could rely on recent PS, I'd use this, then add the border myself.

#### ConvertTo-Html

Produces HTML tables. Depends on your intended use.

#### Community modules

Pick a published module (I have not examined these, I'm demonstrating use of `Find-Module -Tag`):

```
> Find-Module -Repository PSGallery -Tag ascii

Version              Name                                Repository           Description
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------
1.2.2.1              WriteAscii                          PSGallery            Use Svendsen Tech's Write-Ascii function…
1.0.2                Graphical                           PSGallery            Consumes data points as input and plots …
0.0.0.1              Encoding                            PSGallery            Cmdlets for determining file encodings
1.0.3                EncodingAnalyzer                    PSGallery            determines the encoding of any text file
0.1.0.0              SystemSplash                        PSGallery            An ascii system information display for …
0.1.2                SimplyDraw                          PSGallery            ASCII Graphic tooling for PowerShell
1.0.2                Image2Text                          PSGallery            PowerShell Images into ASCII art
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the same but maybe [Format-Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.2)

Edit:
I threw the data you had in your question into a CSV to test it, works about the same I think.
[image]

Comment: I tried Format-Table, but Format-Table result gets scrambled in html output, or when sent to Slack.

Comment: You didn't say anything in your original post that you needed to output to HTML or to Slack. Just that you needed a module similar to prettytable from Python. Format-Table is what Powershell has.

If you want to output it in Slack or HTML, then I would suggest exporting it to a CSV and then converting it to whatever format you need.

Comment: To get results mentioned in question, I ended up repurpose other people codes into **[ConvertTo-SdtMarkdownTable](https://github.com/imajaydwivedi/SQLDBATools/blob/SQLDBATools-v0.0.13/Functions/ConvertTo-SdtMarkdownTable.ps1)**
```
$InputResult | ConvertTo-SdtMarkdownTable -Pretty
```